# None of the VPN Services are working on my computer

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn

I am using Windows 8.1 and have tried to use:

SpotFlux
HotSpotShield
Freedome
but when these services are on, my internet stops working.

As it happens with all of the services I am guessing there is something wrong with my network configuration.

What is possibly wrong?

Comment: I assume there is a problem with the port forwarding.

Comment: @Valinho Any idea, where I can find or change it.

Comment: I installed Intel ProSet software and it works fine now.